# Create Multiple Users with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Hello everyone i trying a create small application. This application will keep max 3 users on it. I'm using a `Sharedpreferences`for save data. But i can't save multiple users i don't have any idea how can i do this. After creating users i want to swap between them and i don't using password for users so system will always can changeable between users.

There is my MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nameText;
    EditText dateText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        dateText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
    }

    public void saveInfo(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("username",nameText.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("date",dateText.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a number in array to achieve this? probably something like this:

```
public void saveInfo(View view,User[] userList) 
{

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedPref.edit();
    for (int i = 0, i < userList.count){
         User user = userList[i]
         editor.putString("username-"+i,user.username);
         editor.putString("date-"+i,user.date);
         editor.apply();
    }

}
```

With this, you can save three users and then call them from the sharedpreferences with username-(number of the user)

Answer (score 0):

so have you tried to set different name for the sharedPreference database for each user?

```
public void saveInfo(View view,User[] userList) 
{
    for (int i = 0, i < userList.count){
         User user = userList[i];

        // I am creating a new shared prefence for each user!
        // by their username.
         SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo_"+user.username.trim(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedPref.edit();

         editor.putString("username",user.username);
         editor.putString("date",user.date);
         editor.apply();
    }

}
```

After that, to get data for a specific user, you just need their username:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo_"+user.username.trim(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String userDate = sharedPref.getString("date", "unknown");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own Class that will hold in fields data that you will need. Also, I suggest you to create an `List` object instead of using array to have more comfortable options like `List.size()`:

```
UserData userData = new UserData(View view, List<User> users);
```

Then hold it in `Map` with your custom unique key to easy get `UserData` in various usage needs:

```
private Map<String, UserData> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();
```